# Tricky sparse matrix manipulation + a surface plot

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have two large, scipy sparse matrices, representing time series data. In the first, each row represents a user's music listening over a number of months (the columns), with each value in the row being the number of songs they listened to that month. Thus the data looks something like this:

```
[[ 866.,  242., ...  72.,  793.],
 [ 566.,  419., ... 886.,  985.],
 [ 755.,  474., ... 999.,  453.],
 ...
 [ 237.,  495., ...  40.,  679.]]
```

The second matrix is the same shape, and maps directly onto the first. That is, each row corresponds to the same user and each column corresponds to the same month as in the other matrix. But each entry in this matrix is a binary (1/0) representing whether a particular event (let's just call it E) occurred in that month for that user. Thus it looks something like this:

```
[[ 1,  0, ... 1,  0],
 [ 0,  1, ... 1,  0],
 [ 1,  0, ... 1,  0],
 ...
 [ 1,  1, ... 1,  1]])
```

Given all that, here's my goal. I want to generate a 3D surface plot with the following dimensions:

X: time (so, months corresponding to the columns in the matrices)
Y: binned music listening (i.e. the values in the first matrix, divvied up into, say, 100 bins)
Z: the proportion of times E in the second matrix occurs for each X,Y pairing.

So, a particular value of Z might be the proportion of times E occurred (i.e. the mean value) for all cases where a user listened to 40-70 songs (or whatever the binning generates) in month 13. The idea is to look at the likelihood of E occurring as a simultaneous function of how much a user has listened, and when they are doing the listening.

I can think of some kludgy ways to do this, but these are big matrices (8 million-ish rows X 90 columns), so I want something pretty efficient. As an intermediate step, I know I need to generate arrays for each of X,Y, and Z, and I'm sure there's some clever manipulation of the matrices I can do to get them, but I'm not sure how to start.

Comment: did you try something already?

Comment: Nothing fruitful. I've been trying to load the matrices into pandas dataframes to facilitate the binning and such, but I'm not sure how best to start.

Comment: Pandas would be one possible solution, but the solution I posted below is exactly intended to be a lightweight alternative to pandas for such common problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical binning or grouping problem; it looks like the following code should do. You should copy and save the grouping code from here:
http://pastebin.com/c5WLWPbp

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import izip
from grouping import group_by

users   = 100
months  = 20
binsize = 40
bins    = 500/binsize+1

counts = np.random.randint(0,500, size=(users, months))
events = np.random.randint(0,2,   size=(users, months))

binned = np.zeros((bins, months), np.float)
for b, c, e in izip(binned.T, counts.T, events.T):
    i, s = group_by(c / binsize).mean(e.astype(np.float))
    b[i] = s
print binned
```

Note that the code isn't vectorized over the months, which isn't ideal, but if we are talking about 90 months and millions of users, the iteration overhead over the months should be insignificant. The grouping which happens behind the scenes is implemented quite efficiently.

Comment: This is great, and to be clear "proportion of times" does imply the mean, as you correctly inferred. Forgive the lack of clarity (I'll edit). One note, is that for this demo, events must be converted to a float (e.g. `events = events.astype(np.float)`) to correctly calculate the mean.

Comment: Oh, and the inititialization of the empty matrix also has to be different (`binned = np.zeros((bins,months, np.float)`)